# replacing variables using batch script

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a template with a `%%a` variable place holder appearing in multiple locations. I have a text file of 300 IDs and I need to write the template to a file once for each ID, substituting the ID for the variable.

I attempted to do this with a batch file, but I think it is having problems with the `<` and `>` characters!

How can I fix this?

Thanks! Code is below

```
            <div class="ct-gallery col-sm-6 col-md-2">
                <a class="ct-js" href="./assets/images/content/%%a.jpg" title="%%a">
                    <figure class="ct-hover">
                        <img src="./assets/images/content/%%a.jpg"  alt="">
                        <figcaption>
                            <h2>%%a</h2>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </a>
            </div>
```

---

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (ids.txt) do (
         echo <div class="ct-gallery col-sm-6 col-md-2"> <a class="ct-js" href="./assets/images/content/%%a.jpg" title="%%a"> <figure class="ct-hover"> <img src="./assets/images/content/%%a.jpg"  alt=""> <figcaption> <h2>%%a/h2> </figcaption> </figure> </a> </div>  >> output.txt
)
```

Comment: Your question content doesn't tell us anything about variables, and your code, _even correcting issues with the `<` and `>` characters_, will probably not do what you want it to either. In order for your question to be on topic here, you should provide the results of your coding attempts and also fully explain what you want the code to do with respect to the text file snippet you've included.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve.  Please be specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix your existing batch code by escaping the problem characters with a `^`.

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (ids.txt) do (
     echo ^<div class="ct-gallery col-sm-6 col-md-2"^> ^<a class="ct-js" href="./assets/images/content/%%a.jpg" title="%%a"^> ^<figure class="ct-hover"^> ^<img src="./assets/images/content/%%a.jpg"  alt=""^> ^<figcaption^> ^<h2^>%%a/h2^> ^</figcaption^> ^</figure^> ^</a^> ^</div^>  >> output.txt
)
```

But your approach destroys the whitespace formatting, and is tedious to implement.

There is a much more elegant solution with pure batch that is quite easy to implement.

Embed the template within your script with a `::label:` in front of each line. You can have as many templates as you want, as long as each one gets a unique `::label:`. The template(s) can appear anywhere within your script - I chose to put it near the top.

Modify your template to use `!a!` instead of `%%a`, and enable delayed expansion. Have your outer loop define an `a` variable for each iterated value, and then add a second FOR /F loop to read the template from your script, preserving all text after the `::label:`, and write out the value. Delayed expansion occurs after FOR variable expansion, so the variable will be replaced as you desire.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
::1:            <div class="ct-gallery col-sm-6 col-md-2">
::1:                <a class="ct-js" href="./assets/images/content/!a!.jpg" title="!a!">
::1:                    <figure class="ct-hover">
::1:                        <img src="./assets/images/content/!a!.jpg"  alt="">
::1:                        <figcaption>
::1:                            <h2>!a!</h2>
::1:                        </figcaption>
::1:                    </figure>
::1:                </a>
::1:            </div>
>>output.txt (
  for /f %%A in (ids.txt) do (
    set "a=%%A"
    for /f "delims=: tokens=1*" %%B in ('findstr "^::1:" "%~f0"') do echo(%%C
  )
)
```

A couple of advantages for this approach:

- You don't have to worry about escaping or quoting any poison characters like `<`.
- White space formatting is easily preserved

There are a couple of limitations:

- Neither your ids nor your template can contain `!` literals unless they are escaped as `^!`.
- None of the output lines in your template may begin with `:`. This limitation can be eliminated with some extra coding, but I doubt you need this complexity.

Answer (score 1):

To simplify the previous batch script, you could run a PowerShell command something like this:

```
$row = '<div class="ct-gallery col-sm-6 col-md-2"> <a class="ct-js" href="./assets/images/content/%%a.jpg" title="%%a"> <figure class="ct-hover"> <img src="./assets/images/content/%%a.jpg"  alt=""> <figcaption> <h2>%%a/h2> </figcaption> </figure> </a> </div>'
Get-Content .\ids.txt | % { $row -replace '%%a',$_ } >> output.txt
```

Note, that single-quotes are encapsulating the `$row` variable to preserve your double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Your wording is a bit unlucky.
I'd use a here string for the div class template and use powershell to insert the IDs (like @muratiacos suggestion). But AFAIK there shouldn't be several div classes with the same name.

powershell script SO49647312.ps1

```
$div_class_template = @"
            <div class="ct-gallery col-sm-6 col-md-2">
                <a class="ct-js" href="./assets/images/content/#insert_id_here#.jpg" title="#insert_id_here#">
                    <figure class="ct-hover">
                        <img src="./assets/images/content/#insert_id_here#.jpg"  alt="">
                        <figcaption>
                            <h2>#insert_id_here#</h2>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </a>
"@

Get-Content .\ids.txt | ForEach-Object {
  $div_class_template.replace("#insert_id_here#",$_) | Out-File -Append output.txt
}
```